# NextJS && axios getServerSideProps encoding problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios

When I use axios in

```
getServerSideProps
```

I get troubles with encoding, so my response.data looks like this:

▼♦♥�Zmo��§�+↨♦�}1d�������♠(���▬
E1►6c��)���↓E�♦Ig�+►�h��(��K��V+Ǳ�↨.�ўs/-�J$%��6♦Il��$���<�~�m�kA���V�Ӛ�����¶e������r→��g�k��h��q�y↑���������‼��x��Gk�

However, when I use axios in Page function, response.data is ok, so I think the problem is somewhere in using axios on server

My code is:

page.tsx

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps((store) => async () => {
  const dispatch = store.dispatch as NextThunkDispatch;
  await dispatch(getFilmsPopular());
  await dispatch(getFilmsAwait());
  return { props: {} }
})
```

action-creator.ts

```
export const getFilmsPopular = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<FilmsAction>) => {
    dispatch({type: FilmsActionTypes.GET_POPULAR_FILMS_LOADING})
    try {
      const res = await http.get(`${API_2_2}/films/top`, {
        params: {
          type: FilmTopEnum.TOP_100_POPULAR_FILMS,
          page: 1
        },
      });
      return dispatch({type: FilmsActionTypes.GET_POPULAR_FILMS, payload: {
        items: res.data.films,
        page: 1,
        pagesCount: res.data.pagesCount
      }})
    } catch (error) {
      return dispatch({
        type: FilmsActionTypes.GET_POPULAR_FILMS_ERROR,
        payload: 'error'
      })
    }
  }
}

export const getFilmsAwait = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<FilmsAction>) => {
    dispatch({type: FilmsActionTypes.GET_AWAIT_FILMS_LOADING})
    try {
      const res = await http.get(`${API_2_2}/films/top`, {
        params: {
          type: FilmTopEnum.TOP_AWAIT_FILMS,
          page: 1
        }
      })
      return dispatch({type: FilmsActionTypes.GET_AWAIT_FILMS, payload: {
        items: res.data.films,
        page: 1,
        pagesCount: res.data.pagesCount
      }})
    } catch (error) {
      return dispatch({
        type: FilmsActionTypes.GET_AWAIT_FILMS_ERROR,
        payload: 'error'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

interceptor.ts

```
export const http = axios.create();

http.interceptors.request.use(req => {
  req.headers = {
    'X-API-KEY': API_KEY,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  }
  return req
})
```

I tried to use fetch() in getServerSideProps() and it worked fine. I also tried to encode in different encodings but it didn't work. I would really like to use axios in my application, but this trouble makes me use fetch() :( Help pls

Comment: see this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74637860/axios-returns-gibberish-with-jsonplaceholder/74663486#74663486)

Comment: try to `JSON.stringify()` your `const res` after receiving the data

Comment: @BenchVue, thx a lot, header `'Accept-Encoding'` helped me!

Comment: @Maxim, sorry I have experience `interceptors` of axios.